# How to set up a Java project with unit tests, references and something like a VS .sln using IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij

I do a lot of c# development work.  Recently, our company decided it was important for webservices to be able to run on Unix machines, and decided that we should write new services in Java as a result.  We've got licenses to IntelliJ, so I'll probably start with that as an IDE.

I've found it pretty easy to find resources about the Java language and the standard libraries.  There are several low level details that are harder to find.

- How do I (how should I?) setup a new project with unit tests?
- How do you manage references? (I spent hours trying to figure out classpath stuff in eclipse a couple years ago)
- How do you setup something equivalent to a .sln file?

So I need pretty low-level help, but without it focusing on code (I don't need help learning to write Hello World, or a for loop).

Comment: I'm not sure this is on topic (SO might be a better fit) but I certainly don't think it's not constructive

Comment: I'm happy to change it or move it, I just need some help with this problem.  If those of you who vote to close can give me some feedback about the problem and guidance on what I should do, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @tallseth: I guess if you would have choosen a different title for your question (like "How to set up a Java project using IntelliJ") instead a title which sounds like "C# vs. Java", the chance of not getting your question closed would be much higher.

Comment: A different question, but perhaps also of interest for you: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/32385/switch-from-c-to-java-which-gotchas-i-should-care?rq=1

Comment: Did you google for "IntelliJ tutorial"? This Wiki should answer most of your questions: http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Setting_up_a_project_in_IntelliJ_IDEA

Comment: tallseth - here's how you can improve your question.  1) get rid of the resource request(s) - they are the source of the not constructive votes.  2) get rid of your 4th bullet, same reason as #1. 3) your first 3 bullets could be broken out into separate questions.  Remember to show what research you've already done and point out where you got stuck.  You have some good questions in there about the transition from C# => Java; you just need to focus a question on each aspect.

Comment: Well, since the OP missed the chance for improving his question, I will give it a try to reopen it.

Comment: "equivalent to a .sln file" from what I see in `.sln` file I am working with now, if you opt for IDEA+Maven combo (which I can safely recommend), your closest "equivalent" will be Maven's pom + IDEA's ipr

Answer (score 2):

Just so you know if you're a C# shop and have significant experience you would be able to use Mono without problem.

**How do I (how should I?) setup a new project with unit tests?**
The same way you would in .NET. The IDE will have the facility to run tests; If you use NUnit you will be happy to know JUnit is what inspired it.

**How do you manage references? (I spent hours trying to figure out classpath stuff in eclipse a couple years ago)**
Maven. I still think it's better and more powerful than nuget. With that said whilst they're comparable they are not one in the same.

**How do you setup something equivalent to a .sln file?**
I don't know about IntelliJ but I've used JetBrains PHPStorm which is based on the same code I believe, you can have multiple projects open at the same time. If you move to Eclipse, it'll be a Workspace.

A lot of big / common .NET libraries (NHibernate, NUnit spring to mind) are ports from Java so if you have experience with these then you should find the transition easier.

Answer (score -2):

We're a .net house and before starting a new product last year were given the "This needs to run on 'nix" mandate also.
We proved our code against mono, and developed our webservices with [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/).

I didn't do the proving, we are now coming up to a first release which we know will be Windows & MS-SQL specific, our next target is to get the full product up and running on Unix, MySQL and Oracle.

We know from our proving work that we'll have more to do integrating with the new databases than we will getting the full product running on 'nix systems.

Not a line of Java was written.